# For loop with if conditional statement

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to understand why first code run only once vs second code is running until it checks all the items in the list.

1.

```
def get_word_over_10_char(list_of_words):
    for word in list_of_words:
        if len(word) > 10:
            return word
        else:
            return ""
```

2. 

```
for word in list_of_words:
    if len(word) > 10:
        return word
return ''
```

word_list = ['soup', 'parameter', 'intuition', 'house-maker', 'fabrication']

Trying to return a word if length is more than 10, and return empty string if less than equal to 10.

Comment: Could you share the entire function and the list to make your problem more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Timo explained in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74577755/15870626), function stops when you use `return`. In order to get all the elements with more than 10 characters, you need to create a list with these words before using `return` :

```
def get_word_over_10_char(list_of_words):
    more_than_10 = []
    for word in list_of_words:
        if len(word) > 10:
            more_than_10.append(word)
    if len(more_than_10)==0:
        return  "Nothing longer than 10"
    return more_than_10
        
word_list = ['soup', 'parameter', 'intuition', 'house-maker', 'fabrication']

print(get_word_over_10_char(word_list))
```

A more pythonic second version using list comprehension to create `more_than_10`:

```
def get_word_over_10_char_v2(list_of_words):
    more_than_10 = [word for word in list_of_words if len(word) > 10]
    if len(more_than_10)==0:
        return  "Nothing longer than 10"
    return more_than_10
        
word_list = ['soup', 'parameter', 'intuition', 'house-maker', 'fabrication']

print(get_word_over_10_char_v2(word_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

How are the items in your list ordered? Because the when the `return` statement in a function is called, the function returns the argument and stops. In the first piece of code, either the `return` in the `if` clause or the `else` is called after the first item in `list_of_words`, so the function stops there. In the second piece of code, the `return word` statement is only called once a word longer than 10 characters is found. From how you describe the problem, I reckon that the last item in your `list_of_words` is longer than 10. So with the second piece of code, you notice that that word is not returned, while you do not notice the empty strings not being returned.

Comment: Words are listed randomly. You are right it is only checking the first word in the list which are longer than 10 and code stops. It is not running again to check rest of words in the list, that is another issue.

Comment: word_list = ['soup', 'parameter', 'intuition', 'house-maker', 'fabrication']